# System fails to boot every Monday

Tags: boot

Every night I shut down my PC and every morning it boots up fine, except Mondays. On Mondays the first boot always gets stuck on the black screen without accepting any keyboard input. If I wait for a couple minutes, then it starts displaying the status. The first error message displayed is that the Accounts service failed to start. As a result, later other services fail to start as well.

If I reboot with a hardware button too soon, then the Grub bootloader gets corrupted and I have to fix it manually with installation USB. However, if I wait until I see `A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)` message and then reboot, everything works fine and it always boots up successfully from the second time.

It could be either some background process running every Monday or every week and just coincidentally match with Monday. I have been experiencing this issue since I installed Ubuntu a few months back.

- System version: Ubuntu 18.04.1
- Kernel version: 4.15.0-38-generic
- SSD: Samsung 860 EVO

Where could I look for any regular jobs that Ubuntu is doing upon boot-up and how to start debugging this issue since input is unavailable during boot?

Comment: Read `man journalctl`. For `cron` jobs, `journalctl /usr/sbin/cron` will show log messages.

Comment: I have a single `cron` job set up which is `0 * * * *`, however it does not correlate with boot up times.